# Передать параметр в middleware Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Знаю что можно передавать параметры так:

```
...->middleware('name:param')
```

Но как передать параметр из ссылки?

```
/objects/edit/{object}
```

Вот мне этот {object} и нужно кинуть в мидлваре. В методе, этот параметр - экземпляр класса. Посути один об'экт из всема вытекающими.

Comment: Связать в поставщике служб создание экземпляра с ключевым словом `object` и просто вызвать в нужном месте и в нужное время, `app()->make('object')`. Или https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Middleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // если у вас роутер отдает object как id (строку)
        $objectId = $request->route('object'));
        $object = Object::find($objectId);

        // если у вас роутер отдает object как объект 
        $object = $request->route('object'));

        $response = $next($request);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Если у вас роутер отдает строку, а вам хочется сразу объект - можно забиндить самому.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-model-binding

Так же биндинг происходит за счет того, что Object должен быть указан в качестве параметра метода контроллера, иначе биндинг DI контейнера не сработает.

```
class ObjectController()
{
    public function method(Object $object){
       //
   } 
}
```